# Vortordo de adverboj - kiom, kiel, kaj kiam gravas?

Tags: adverbs, word-order

Jen frazoj ŝajne simplaj.

> Estas **bone** legi libron.
> **Simple** pensu!

La unua, laŭ kunteksto, evidente signifas ke legi libron estas afero bona. Sed, ĉu ia ajn nuanco aŭ signifo malsimila estus, se la "bone" estus metita antaŭen de la "estas"? Tio estas, krom laŭ nur kunteksto, kiel povus esti sciite, ĉu la adverbo rilatas al la "estas", kaj ĉu la adverbo rilatas al la i-verbo, speciale kiam pli ol unu adverbo estas inter la "estas" kaj la i-verbo?

La dua, laŭ mia kompreno, povas signifi aŭ "pensu en maniero simpla" aŭ kvazaŭ "tio, kion diras mi al vi, estas tre simpla: pensu!". La malsamo sentita estus pli klara en la angla: "simply think" kompare al "think simply". Ĉu tia distingo estas ankaŭ en Esperanto? Ĉu frazo "simple pensu simple" senchavus?

Do, en tiaj frazoj, kiom, kiel, kaj kiam gravas tio, kien metita estas la adverbo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La ordo ne gravas en la rilato adverbo-verbo (jen du ekzemploj de Tekstaro, Zamenhofaj)

> mi donas publike por tio, ke

> mi publike diras mem,

Pri viaj frazoj:

> Estas bone legi libron

`bone` [perverbe priskribas](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortoj/uzo.html#i-clt) `legi`, ne estas alia eblo.

> Simple pensu!

En Esperanto tio, same kiel `pensu simple!` priskribas la manieron pensi.

Pro nacilingva influo oni povus emi uzi `simple` kiam fakte `nur` estas la ĝusta adverbo:

```
pensu nur!
nur pensu!
```

En la Fundamenta Krestomatio vi trovos:

```
por vi mi estas preta ĉion fari, – nur ordonu!
```

Ekzemple, en mia denaska, mi povus traduki tiun lastan `nur` per `simple`, sed tio ne funkcias en Esperanto. `simple pensu!`/`pensu simple!` signifas `malkomplike pensu!`/`pensu malkomplike!`.